# Getting Levenshtein distance from `diifflib.ndiff`

Tags: python, string, levenshtein-distance, difflib, string-algorithm

The levenshtein distance algorithm in Python is too slow as I am comparing many strings.

So I want to use `difflib.ndiff` to do it.

I tried parsing the output by interpreting "+", "-", " " from the result of `ndiff`, but failed.

Here is what I tried:

```
import difflib
edit_dist = sum(op[0] == "-" for op in difflib.ndiff("split", "sitting"))
```

But the returned result is incorrect.

I want to use solutions from `stdlib`. Any advice / solutions?

P.S. I need to get the nunber edit distance, not ratio so `SequenceMatcher.ratio` doesn't work

Comment: How much is "too slow" ? How many strings of what length in how much time ? Why do you have to **only** use the stdlib ?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/calculate-levenshtein-distance-between-two-strings-in-python